# How do I apply the .cast() method to the output of a comparison operator?

Tags: c++, eigen

I want to apply the threshold function to a bunch of fuzzy values (floats):

```
template <typename Derived>
void Threshold(Eigen::ArrayBase<Derived>& params)
{
  params = (params >= 0.0f).cast<float>();
}
```

The idea is that I end up with a bunch of 1s and 0s (`float`) where there used to be fuzzy values. But when I do this I get the following error:

> src/core/Neuron.h: In static member function ‘static void
>   Neuron::Threshold(Eigen::ArrayBase&)’:
>   src/core/Neuron.h:119:43: error: expected primary-expression before
>   ‘float’    params = (params >= 0.0f).cast();
>                                              ^ src/core/Neuron.h:119:43: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘float’ make: *** [src/core/Cell.o] Error 1

Clearly I'm not using the `cast` method properly. I've looked at the [Documentation](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/classEigen_1_1ArrayBase.html#a660200abaf1fc4b888330a37d6132b76) and it gives the following prototype for the `cast` method:

```
internal::cast_return_type< Derived,const CwiseUnaryOp<internal::scalar_cast_op<typename internal::traits<Derived>::Scalar, NewType>, const Derived> >::type cast () const inline
```

I don't really understand what all that means, but I'm guessing I might be missing a template parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
params = (params >= 0.0f).template cast<float>();
```

This usage basically is just an overloading of the `template` keyword. Here, it's a hint to the compiler that you are trying to call a member template. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords/613132#613132) for full details.

Comment: That works. Could you explain why? I don't really understand the syntax you're using..

Comment: I added a brief explanation, and a link to a (much) longer one.